# CSS @keyframes animation flicker

Tags: android, ios, css

How to fix [`@-webkit-keyframes`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_keyframes.asp) animation flicker at the end of its iteration?

It is very noticeable on Android 2 on animating with CSS3 [`transform`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) values `translate`, `translate3d` and `opacity`.

You might notice in some posts a suggestions to fix it with:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

or

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

But after testing it on Android 2.3, I noticed than non of them really fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

George Hess published in his blog a [working fix](http://georgehess.com/post/2054803814/css-keyframe-animation-flicker) for it, mentioning:

> The flicker is caused by the animation resetting to the beginning
>   keframe for just a split second. This happens even if you have styled
>   the animated CSS class to stay where it is and inherit the last
>   keyframe’s styles upon completing the animation. The only solution I
>   could come up with is to use more than 2 keyframes.

For example, if the following code flickers:

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'slide-in' {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

changing it to the following will fix the problem

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'slide-in' {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
    99% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
    to {} /* equals `100% {}` Leave it empty to fix the flicker */
}
```

**Conclusion:** Leave empty (do not set parameters to) the end of animation duration `to {}`/`100% {}` and beside set end of animation parameters in `99% {}` or else duration.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get @Binyamin's solution to work, but managed to solve this issue whilst debugging another one, just by adding `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`