# How to prevent safari @-webkit-keyframe animation flicker

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Occasionally, when executing a css animation, Safari will make the animation flicker. I've been looking far and wide for a solution, but nothing I found works.

I've got the following html (shortened, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y37ugp5/2/) for more fun)

```
<div class="dot"></div>
```

And the following CSS

```
.dot {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #1A3853;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.dot:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #237CC6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: -1;

    animation-name: fading;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-animation-name: fading;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fading {
    from  { height: 8px; width: 8px; margin-left: -4px; top: 0; opacity: .7; }
    99%   { height: 26px; width: 26px; margin-left: -13px; top: -9px; opacity: 0; }
    to    { }
}

@keyframes fading {
    from  { height: 8px; width: 8px; margin-left: -4px; top: 0; opacity: .7; }
    to    { height: 26px; width: 26px; margin-left: -13px; top: -9px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

Chrome and firefox both execute the animation flawlessly, but Safari occasionally freaks out. I've already tried everything that's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429575/css-keyframes-animation-flicker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688959/how-do-i-prevent-safari-css-keyframe-animation-flicker) but it doesn't seem to solve it for me.

Comment: Safari is a problem child, tbh. It is optimised for battery life and not performance, which is okay, I guess, but it causes issues like this. Try animating anything with the javascript `onscroll` and it will work everywhere but safari. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - and could solve it with the correct server time in the apache configuration.